# Compare folder A and subfolder B and show files that are in folder A but not in subfolder B

Tags: python

I have 1,880 HTML files in folder A and only 50 HTML files in subfolder B. So the code must show me each file, the different between 1880 - 50.
This is my code, but it didn't work. I believe because there are Folder and Subfolder, and Python cannot distinguish between them.

```
import os

folder1 = r"C:\Folder-Oana\extracted"
folder2 = r"C:\Folder-Oana\extracted\translated"

# Obține lista de fișiere HTML din fiecare folder
html_files_folder1 = [f.lower() for f in os.listdir(folder1) if f.lower().endswith('.html')]
html_files_folder2 = [f.lower() for f in os.listdir(folder2) if f.lower().endswith('.html')]

# Găsește diferențele între cele două liste de fișiere
missing_files = list(set(html_files_folder1) - set(html_files_folder2))

# Afișează fișierele care lipsesc
if missing_files:
    print("The HTML files found in folder 1 but not in folder 2 are:")
    for filename in missing_files:
        print(filename)
else:
    print("There are no HTML files found in folder 1 but not in folder 2.")
```

This is the wrong output, because I have files: `There are no HTML files found in folder 1 but not in folder 2.`

**EXAMPLE:**

**c:\Folder-Oana\extracted**

```
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\translated\    <DIR>   01/05/2024 13:36    ----
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\2.html
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\3.html
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\4.html
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\5.html
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\11.html
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\12.html
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\13.html
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\14.html
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\15.html
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\16.html
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\17.html
```

**c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\translated**

```
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\translated\11.html
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\translated\12.html
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\translated\13.html
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\translated\14.html
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\translated\15.html
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\translated\16.html
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\translated\17.html
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\translated\18.html
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\translated\19.html
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\translated\24.html
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\translated\25.html
c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\translated\26.html
```

**The output:**

```
2.html
3.html
4.html
5.html
```

**Version 2:** (also, doesn't detect the files only from `\extracted folder`, but all html files.)

```
import os
import filecmp

def compare_folders(folder1, folder2):
    dcmp = filecmp.dircmp(folder1, folder2)
    diff_files = dcmp.diff_files
    
    if diff_files:
        print(f"The following files are different between {folder1} and {folder2}:")
        for file in diff_files:
            print(f" - {file}")
    else:
        print(f"No differences found between {folder1} and {folder2}.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder1 = r"C:\Folder-Oana\extracted"
    folder2 = r"C:\Folder-Oana\extracted\translated"
    compare_folders(folder1, folder2)
```

Comment: Your code looks to be fine indeed. Did you check if `html_files_folder1` and `html_files_folder2` contain what you expect? Who knows, maybe you made a typo in the folder paths?

Comment: yes. Many times. As I say before, I have 1,880 HTML files in folder A and only 50 HTML files in subfolder B. See print screen `https://snipboard.io/Ob1Ugp.jpg`

Comment: What do `print(len(html_files_folder1))` and `print(len(html_files_folder2))` give? Are they what you would expect?

Comment: I edit the subject. See the output I expect

Comment: Your Version 1 works perfectly fine on my sysetm. for your version 2 exchange `dcmp.diff_files` with `dcmp.left_only` to find files that are in the left directory (folder1) only.

Comment: By the way, your screenshot shows no files in folder extracted, that are not also in translated. Are you ___really___ sure, your inputs are correct?

Comment: What about the troubleshooting suggestion slothrop made? What happens when you try printing the lengths of your two lists?

Answer (score 0):

It may not detect subfolders when seeing your code.

Please find the updated code for your issue.

```
import os

folder1 = r"C:\Folder-Oana\extracted"
folder2 = r"C:\Folder-Oana\extracted\translated"

# Function to get all HTML files recursively from a folder
def get_html_files(directory):
    html_files = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            if file.lower().endswith('.html'):
                html_files.append(os.path.join(root, file).lower())
    return html_files

# Get HTML files from both folders and their subfolders
html_files_folder1 = get_html_files(folder1)
html_files_folder2 = get_html_files(folder2)

# Find differences between the two lists of files
missing_files = list(set(html_files_folder1) - set(html_files_folder2))

# Display files that are in folder1 but not in folder2
if missing_files:
    print("The HTML files found in folder 1 but not in folder 2 are:")
    for filename in missing_files:
        print(filename)
else:
    print("There are no HTML files found in folder 1 but not in folder 2.")
```

Comment: almost good, but not good. Because, for example: `c:\folder-oana\extracted\52.html` it is also in `c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\translated\52.html`  I believe there is a Python major bug.

Comment: the same problem. It gives me all files, not just the files from `\extracted` folder

Comment: I don't think the asker is trying to find files recursively in subfolders; unless they clarify otherwise, it sounds like they want to compare only the files in the top folder with the files in one specific subfolder.

Answer (score -2):

**WORKS. The problem was with the version of Python. Thank you!**

```
import os

def find_files_only_in_folder(folder, subfolder):
    folder_files = set(os.listdir(folder))
    subfolder_files = set(os.listdir(subfolder))

    files_only_in_folder = folder_files - subfolder_files

    print(f"Files only in {folder} and not in {subfolder}:")
    for file in files_only_in_folder:
        print(f"- {file}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    folder_path = r"c:\Folder-Oana\extracted"
    subfolder_path = r"c:\Folder-Oana\extracted\translated"

    find_files_only_in_folder(folder_path, subfolder_path)
```

Comment: What version was it? Did you switch to a different one? How did you fix it?

Comment: I just uninstall the 2 old versions, and I install the last version Python 3.12.1